# I try to open inboxFragment in my fragment tab but in inboxfragment it shows me empty, there should be at least text, where do i make mistake?

Tags: java, android, tabs, fragment, swipe

I can't see any text in my inbox fragment or in friends fragment, I can see section names inbox and friends but when I click them then there is empty page.

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.ahmetyuva.ribbit;

import java.util.Locale;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; 
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar; 
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; 
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager; 
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction; 
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager; 
import android.view.Gravity; 
import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.MenuItem; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.TextView; 
import java.util.Locale;

import android.content.Intent; 
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; 
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar; 
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; 
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager; 
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction; 
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; 
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager; 
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter; 
import android.content.Context;

import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager; 
import android.util.Log; 
import android.view.Gravity; 
import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.MenuItem; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.parse.Parse; 
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics; 
import com.parse.ParseException; 
import com.parse.ParseObject; 
import com.parse.ParseUser; 
import com.parse.SignUpCallback;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser == null) {

            navigateToLogin();
        }
        else{
            Log.i(TAG, currentUser.getUsername());
        }

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });



        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    private void navigateToLogin() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
            ParseUser.logOut();
            navigateToLogin();

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

    }
}
```

This is InboxFragment.java

```
package com.ahmetyuva.ribbit;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment; 
import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.ViewGroup;

    /** * Created by ahmetyuva on 06/04/15. */ public class InboxFragment extends ListFragment { @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inbox, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

and this is SectionsPagerAdapter.java

```
    package com.ahmetyuva.ribbit;

    /** * Created by ahmetyuva on 06/04/15. */

    import android.content.Context; import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager; import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

    import java.util.Locale;

    /** * A {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to * one of the sections/tabs/pages. */ public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    protected Context mContext;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new InboxFragment();
            case 1:
                return new FriendsFragment();
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

fragment_inbox.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/empty_inbox_label"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what should be displayed ? show your xml

Comment: <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/empty_inbox_label"/>

Comment: problem is it does not show anything, i change tabs easily but inside tabs it white screen

Comment: what is in your R.layout.fragment_inbox ?

Comment: i've just edited, you can see at the bottom of the question as fragment_inbox.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">


            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_above="@android:id/empty"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@android:id/empty"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:text="@string/empty_inbox_label"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: its still white screen unfortunately.

Comment: @AhmetYuva ,enable Developer Options on your phone, then check "Show layout boundaries" option and see what is going on there

Comment: i checked "show layout boundaries" as well but still nothing changed

Comment: so there are no boundaries, right ? Try to set the background of your fragment layout to green for example and see if screen willl be green or remove that ListView and Hardcode some text value to textView (@string/empty_inbox_label value is set correctly ?) and so on, you should detect the problem eventually